# consuming stored events via several consumers and event handlers

Tags: c#, events, reactivex

I am currently using this pattern to deal with events coming from some event sink (e.g. enterprise service bus, queue, EventStore). The idea is to instantiate several IEventWorkers (see concrete example below) in a list and passing events on, for example, by invoking  the HandleEvent methods of each instance whilst looping over the list. This is the basic code of an IEventWorkers concrete:

```
public class EventWorker : IEventWorker 
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> CreateEventHandlerMapping()
    {
        return new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>
        {
        {typeof (Event1), o => Handle(o as Event1)},
        {typeof (Event2), o => Handle(o as Event2)},
        };
    }

    private void Handle(Event1 eventToHandle)
    {

    }

    private void Handle(Event2 eventToHandle)
    {

    }

    public void HandleEvent(IEvent evt)
    {
        var eventType = evt.GetType();
        if (_eventHandlerMapping.ContainsKey(eventType))
        {
        _eventHandlerMapping[eventType](evt);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe there is a better way to do this?

PS:

[This](https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2015/07/16/event-sourcing-applied-the-read-model/) comes quite close to what I am trying to achieve. I do not fully understand how the ObserverRegistry would work to distribute all events coming from, for example, an event queue.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite broad in nature; perhaps a little too much. I encourage you to refine it.

However, you ask for potential improvements, and I can think of at least one thing specific enough:

- You may use double-dispatch instead of type-casting for type-safety.

See [the visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) for more information. In your case, you would create an `Accept`-like method on `IEvent` and call it in `HandleEvent`:

```
public void HandleEvent(IEvent evt)
{
    evt.Accept(this);
}
```

Accept methods on event types would look like:

```
public void Accept(IEventWorker worker)
{
    worker.Handle(this);
}
```

(While this is still a virtual call of course, notice the handler method overload is now selected statically. This is in contrast to your existing runtime dictionary lookup.)

The `IEventWorker` interface would mandate a method per event type, which is the equivalent of "registering" them, although this time in a type-safe manner. Note that this would change their access level on your implementation, which is fine.

You can then remove the mapping dictionary entirely; you're now using the virtual table of the class to the same effect.

I wouldn't jump on also claiming performance improvements (if it even mattered in your scenario), but if it is important you may want to test and see (you should at least expect better performance).